# How to print multiple parameters using Method reference in java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, method-reference

I'm trying to print out basic `hashmap` with twoin java.

```
Map<Integer, String> mp = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
mp.put(10, "apple");
mp.put(20, "orange");
mp.put(30, "banana");
```

But I can't figure out how to print multiple parameters, when it comes to `method reference` in java8.

I tried something like this. But it's giving me compile errors.

```
mp.forEach(System.out::println(i+" "+s););
```

Please help me to figure out this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a separate method, for example:

```
public static <K, V> void printEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> e) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}

map.entrySet().forEach(Demo::printEntry);
```

Or, if the `Map.Entry<K, V>.toString()` meets your requirements:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

// 20=orange
// 10=apple
// 30=banana
```

**Edit:** Also, following @Holger's advice, you can safely omit the type parameters as long as the code inside the method doesn't depend on them:

```
public static void printEntry(Object k, Object v) {
    System.out.println(k + " " + v);
}

map.forEach(Demo::printEntry);
```

Comment: @Oleksandr `Map` has `forEach` too, no need for `entrySet`

Comment: @Oleksandr point is that `entrySet::forEach` does the same thing as `Map::forEach`

Comment: I second the thought from Eugene, the readability difference between our answers is quite visible for that reason. Also, side note the output shall include space before and after `=` if your same code is executed which would produce different output to that of `toString()` if you meant comparing them by any chance.

Comment: @oleksandar can you please explain to me how println figure out to print the object. (This is may be dumb to ask but I really don't understand it)

Comment: @pippi What really happens: `System.out.println(obj) -> obj.toString()` where `obj` is a `hashMapEntry` that has its own `toString` method implementation that returns `key + "=" + value;`

Comment: The type parameters `<K, V>` are obsolete. You could simply declare `printEntry(Map.Entry<?,?> e)`. But even better would be to declare `printEntry(Object key, Object value)` and use `map.forEach(Demo::printEntry)`

Comment: @Eugene `Map.entrySet().forEach` accepts a `Consumer<Entry>` whereas `Map.forEach` accepts a `BiConsumer`. That’s not exactly the same, especially when you want to use method references.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the very helpful advice! Should I add this as an edit to my answer?

Answer (score 8):

Might be contradictory to other answers, yet I really don't see a need of you using a method reference here. IMHO,

```
mp.forEach((i, s) -> System.out.println(i + " " + s));
```

is far better than method reference for such a use case.

Comment: exactly the reason I said this can be done in place, with a lambda... Still, 1+

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you for the answer. I know it is easy through lambda expression. I was just checking whether method reference can replace this using a simpler way.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The language does not allow that, there is no implicit i and s there that can be passed to a method reference that way. What u can do, no idea why, but you could:

```
private static <K, V> void consumeBoth(K k, V v) {
     //Log how u want this
}
```

And use it with:

```
map.forEach(Yourclass::consumeBoth)
```

But this can be done in place with a lambda expression, I really see no benefit for this small example

Comment: This solution is straight and stays in the logic of providing unwrapped data for the entries. Manipulating directly the unwrapped key and value from the entryset is really simpler than invoking `getKey()` and `getValue()` (+1)

Comment: @davidxxx Agreed, just didn't think about that from the beginning. That's why I love SO :)

Comment: @Oleksandr  Indeed we learn things everyday :) It is definitively a great place to share and learn :)

Comment: IMHO the [use case doesn't even need a method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237646/1746118)...or does it benefit anyhow?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot specify the whitespace by using the method reference `System.out::println`.
The argument passed to `System.out::println` is inferred by the `BiConsumer` parameter of `Map.forEach(BiConsumer)`.

But you could format the expected `String` with `map()`, in this way, the argument inferred in `System.out::println` would be the formatted string, what you need  :

```
mp.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .map(e-> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also print using entrySet

```
 mp.entrySet().forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, but using Apache API Pair class (ImmutablePair) in Java 8.

`Stream.of(ImmutablePair.of("A", "1"), ImmutablePair.of("B", "0"))      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight));`

Hope it helps.